# How should I approach this section of Beethovens Op2 No1

Tags: piano, technique, beethoven, hand-independence

[image]

I started this piece around 2 days ago for my grade 8 piano exam and I've been having a nightmare with the beginning section(red circles). I can play the rest of the piece with no problem but the beginning keeps giving me a headache. When I try playing with both hands my right hand keeps failing. I just don't understand why I can't play it.. I've played much more technically demanding pieces and my teacher even told me that this was a relatively easy piece.

Comment: How does your right hand keep failing? Specifically?

Comment: When I try to play the triplets(While playing the left hand as well), my right fingers just seem to lose strength and end up messing up the rhythm. It's fine when I play just my right hand only.

Comment: Play it without the triplets, then. Keep playing it until you can do it in your sleep. *Then* you can start working on the triplets with your right hand. When you've got them down as effortlessly as the left hand chords, *then* you can start reassembling both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you getting the rhythm and the *"Left-Right-Coordination"* right. I found it helpful in such cases to reduce the pattern to a more simple rhythmic pattern and practice these in a loop until they feel save.

[image]

In Example `A` I just tab a simple 4th rhythm in the left hand, while getting used to the rhythmic pattern in the right hand in relation to the beat. Then in example `B` and `C` I'm introducing the 4th breaks. You can do different variations for `B` and start introducing the breaks in different ways then shown here. Experiment your way of getting closer until you get `C` straight.

Then you can adapt those rhythmic patterns being played with real notes. This does not necessarily mean you got to start with the notes from *Beethoven's Op.2 Nr.1*, you could also improvise with this patterns or play it in different *(maybe easier)* keys. Have fun... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Play it SLOWLY.  Preferably with a metronome set to 8ths at 120.  Yes, THAT slowly.  Maybe with slightly exaggerated finger lifting to give the musical equivalent of chear diction.  You should discover where you're fumbling.

Comment: You might also want to experiment with different fingerings.

Comment: 100% agree with the reduced tempo approach. Watch the left-right coordination, while doing so. Counting 8th is also pretty decent recommendation to get clear how the rhythm is subdivided.